# DrawerLayout set drag area vertically

Tags: android, drawerlayout

I am using DrawerLayout and I have reduced the dragging area horizontally via reflection as someone suggested. It's a hack, I know, but it works.

Is there a way to reduce the dragging area vertically ? Say only top half of or bottom half of the screen allowed to drag ?